# Possibly bad video driver for AMD Radeon R7 graphics

Tags: amd-graphics, 18.04, gpu-driver

I am trying to run Ubuntu 18.04 on a computer with an AMD processor and AMD Radeon R7 graphics. I believe the driver for AMD Radeon R7 graphics has problems and may be buggy. I have had a problem with Totem which I asked in a separate question, but I have another problem where (sometimes) if I suspend the computer then bring it back to life, I get a hash of colors and pixels and cannot get the computer back without shutting it down (and losing a lot of work).

Is there anything I can do to improve things? Also, is there any place where I can report problems with drivers and possible bugs? What are my options? There is a driver produced by AMD for Ubuntu 16.04 but it doesn't work with the 18.04 kernel.

Thanks in advance for any help you can give.

Comment: I advise you to follow this link. https://launchpad.net/~oibaf/+archive/ubuntu/graphics-drivers

Comment: Thank you so much! I believe that installing these drivers has solved my problem when suspending my computer, but unfortunately, not the psychedelic playback of Totem. I'm going to play with it some more and I will probably mark your answer as the accepted answer. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't want to leave the wrong impression for those who might be searching for the same issues as I am. Actually, this solved nothing. Someone in another thread gave me the answer to the psychedelic video playback. I am still having the problem with hash and having to shutdown the computer after bring it out of suspend.

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: Please use the latest available driver from AMD. Adding the links here:
[Radeon driver (amdgpu-unified) v21.50](https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-50)
[Instructions for installation](https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/21.40/)

Please ensure that you uninstall all previous versions, by using:

> $> amdgpu-uninstall

Exactly the same issue: Can't resume after suspend
Using a laptop with AMD PRO A12-9800B APU, and Ubuntu 18.04 (actually Kubuntu; although this shouldn't really matter)
Realized that this might be a driver issue.
Managed to solve by the following steps:

1. Download Radeon R7 driver for Ubuntu 18.04 at the following link:
   https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-prorad-lin-18-40
2. Extract the package contents, by using the steps on:
   https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/amd-18.30/install-prereq.html
3. Install the drivers, by using the steps on:
   https://amdgpu-install.readthedocs.io/en/amd-18.30/install-script.html

**NOTE:** If any of the packages fail to install, due to re-direction loops, you might have to install those packages manually.

After the installation is completed successfully, reboot.
This issue should now be resolved.